# Regex for pattern match and replace

Tags: regex

I have several paths in a file which have this pattern

```
/directory/dir/A/
/directory/dir/B/
/directory/dir/C/
/directory/dir/D/
```

I want a regex pattern to replace them with

```
/directory/dir/new-path-A/
/directory/dir/new-path-B/
/directory/dir/new-path-C/
/directory/dir/new-path-D/
```

Thanks

Comment: What would be the required one if the path is `directory/dir/A/dir/A` ? Do you want to change the last one only ?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jens & NeverHopeless. I have chosen @anubhava solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search pattern:

```
(/dir/)[^/]*
```

Replacement:

```
$1new-path-
```

**Java code:**

```
String repl = input.replacAll("(/dir/)[^/]*", "$1new-path-");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uO5gL1/1)

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your quick response. Appreciate the help